# How to receive a fractional number as parameter to my function?

Tags: solidity, mist, data-types

In my Solidity smart contract, there is a function that needs to receive an amount as parameter.

This parameter is the value to be used for a transfer function. Considering the user may need to transfer 1.25 Ethers, how can he input this data, as there´s not a data type for it?

Answer (score 5):

For the transfer you can specify the amount in wei, which would be 1250000000000000000 for 1.25 ETH. For that you can use unsigned integer. No need for decimals.

In most cases (not only for ETH) you can avoid using decimals by scaling the value to the desired precision.

Comment: see also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19629/ethereum-tokens-and-decimals

Comment: Yes, this is a work around.  Technically, it works.

But in real life it´s not a good approach asking the user to input somethiing like 18 digits just to mean "1". Is there another way?

Comment: You don‘t have to present it like that in your User Interface. IMHO, technically smart contract is backend code. Anyway nothing for non-techies without a nice frontend.

Comment: OK, I guess this is an front-end problem.  Today I´m using Mist, but in production environment, using web3.js I guess I will not have this problem anymore.  Thanks