# Triggering contract fallback function by sending ether from another contract

Tags: solidity, ether, remix, rinkeby

```
contract A {

uint public u;
event abc(address);

constructor() payable{
    u=100;
}

function () payable{
    emit abc(msg.sender);
    u = 25;
}

function setu(uint i) {
    u = i;
}

function getBalance() view returns(uint){
    return address(this).balance;    
}
```

}

```
contract B {

uint public a;
A ac;

function(){
    a= 20;
}
constructor() payable {
    a=10;
}

function send(A b){
    b.call.gas(210000).value(100 wei)();    
} 

function getBalance() view returns(uint){
    return address(this).balance;    
}
```

}

I have updated the code.
Now, I am passing gas along with the call to avoid gas estimation failure.

I am trying to trigger contract `A`'s fallback function by sending some ether by calling `send` function from contract `Attacker`.

This works fine in Remix using javascript VM but getting failed in Rinkeby.

Comment: Please share your Rinkeby transaction details and how you are testing it.

Comment: when I call `Send()` of `Contract Attacker` it shows Gas Estimation Failed error.

Comment: Simply you have too much elaboration in your fallback function. See my answer in: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60079/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-deployed-but-showing-error-while-sending-ether/60087#60087

Comment: @LauriPeltonen It is working when I use Javascript VM but transaction fails on Rinkeby.
TxId: 0x7e4ef5707ffe11b8a04dcc85e8be7057c92bb56c957243736af5c9998b80302